# Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4 - Wired connection works but it's not detected

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, raspberrypi, wired

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with Plasma and on my Pi 4 I can access the web with a wired connection but the system still says that I'm offline.

For instance, I can update packages from ssh but not with Discover which says that I'm offline. The network applet has the wired connection icon but if I open the applet it shows no connection and the mouse over label says that I'm disconnected.

After installing kdenetwork I can see wireless connections but not the wired one.

This is my `ifconfig eth0`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.1.87  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe27:38a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
inet6 2001:b07:ae5:db90:dea6:32ff:fe27:38a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
ether dc:a6:32:27:38:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 306938  bytes 97042582 (97.0 MB)
RX errors 0  dropped 1171  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 485041  bytes 661433930 (661.4 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

With `ethtool eth0` I receive

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current messsudo age level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Does you distro an Rpi official?
Have you tried in wlan connection? if so, what is the result?
Do you have wlan turned on while using eth0? Try to disconnect wlan, it could generate some sort of IP conflicts

Comment: It's the official Ubuntu Server image for Pi 4 with Plasma as DE. I can connect to wifi network and when connected I have both wlan0 and eth0 with two IP addresses.

Comment: Try to disconnect wlan, it could generate some sort of IP conflicts

Comment: No, IP are different because I use static IPs inside my local network. By the way, wlan is disconnected.

Comment: Have you tried with DHCP ip? you say can't see wired connection, but eth0 it's your wired connection

Comment: I received the IP via DHCP: my router it's configured to use always the same address for the same device (for instance, if I change OS on my Pi I'll receive the same address). I can't see the wired connection from network manager and other software like Discovery or Cockpit but eth0 it's working and this is strange.

Comment: if you do ifconfig, does eth0 appears? one time i changed dhcp to static, and my eth0 ip connection disapeared, only ip, but eth0 was visible and not wroking

Comment: You can see my ifconfig in my first post. DHCP works correctly, even because I have no issue with other PC, also my Pi get the correct IP, I can navigate on the web, use ssh and so on. Eth0 appears correctly but strangely isn't visible to network manager.

Comment: if your problem it's only not viewing eth0 connection, and everything works, don't boder, or just do a fresh install in a new partition to see what happens.

Comment: It's boring because some application will not work properly